# Error when trying to use Media gallery

Tags: media

I'm using Media gallery 7.x-1.0-beta8 with Media 7.x-1.4 module in drupal 7.34. Whenever I try to add a picture to my gallery I get this error [LINK](http://prntscr.com/5ra1cu)

Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_info_file_types() in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\media\media.module on line 1085

Is there some way I could fix this? I tried using different versions of both Media gallery and Media, but I keep getting some weird incompatibilities. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because sounds like a bug report on [bug report for media module](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/media?categories=1)